# Joins In Cake. Get User Data with tutorials count using joins and sorting in cakephp

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, cakephp

I want user data along with their created tutorials count in descending order.

My mysql query is.

```
SELECT Users.id, Users.first_name, Users.last_name, COUNT(Tutorials.id) as counttotal
FROM users Users JOIN tutorials as Tutorials on Users.id = Tutorials.user_id GROUP BY Tutorials.user_id
ORDER BY counttotal DESC LIMIT 5
```

My approach in `cakePHP` as follows:

```
$userdata = array();
                $options['fields'] = array(
                           'Users.id', 
                           'Users.first_name', 
                           'Users.last_name', 
                           'COUNT(tutorials.id)'
                   );
                $options['joins'] = array(
                                          array(
                                             'table' => 'tutorials',
                                             'alias' => 'Tutorials',
                                             'type' => 'INNER',
                                             'conditions' => array(
                                                'Users.id = Tutorials.user_id'
                                            )
                                          ) 
                                    );
                $options['group'] = array('Users.id');
                $result = $this->Users->find('all', $options);
```

It's showing some error.

Comment: Whenever you receive an error, please post the _complete_ error message (including filename and line number), and include the related stacktrace (you'll find both in your CakePHP `/logs/`)! Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: I got this error message. : Error: 
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(`tutorials__id`) FROM users Users GROUP BY Users.id' at line 1

Comment: Post the raw query from $this->Users so it will be simpler to find where the error is: `->sql()` or `debug()`